# Ideal data model for relational database

Tags: database-design, sequelize.js, relational-database

I have 3 objects (Vendor, Manager, Customer) each of which has 1 logo. Each object has a data model as follows (using Manager as an example):

```
 const Manager = sequelize.define('manager', {
    id: {
      ...
    },
    user_id: {
      ...
    },
    name: {
      ...
    },
    // other stuff
})

  Manager.associate = (models) => {
    Manager.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
  }
```

The Logo model is as follows:

```
  const Logo = sequelize.define('logo', {
    id: {
      ...
    },
    owner_id: {
      ...
    },
    url: {
      ...
    },
    width: {
      ...
    },
    // other stuff
})
```

If I put all the logos in one Logo model, then the owner_id does not know whether to refer to the Manager, Vendor, or Customer.

What is considered proper:

1. Make a separate ManagerLogo, VendorLogo, CustomerLogo, with the owner_id referencing the relevant Manager.id, Vendor.id and Customer.id ?
2. Add additional fields to Logo (e.g., an ENUM type='manager' | 'vendor' | 'customer') to enable pointing the owner_id to the appropriate model.
3. Another method ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Considering your Manager, Vendor, and Customer entities each relate to a User entity, you can relate your Logo entity to the User entity as well.

Don't do your second choice.

**Edit** ...

You can put a `logo_id` column in your Customer or Manager table instead of a `customer_id` or `manager_id` column in your Logo table. You could also put a `logo_id` column in User or Vendor. (The `logo_id` values should all be nullable.)  That way you can create the same sort of logo for various different purposes without making your schema too complex.

Comment: Thanks. Each of Manager, Vendor, and Customer relate to 1 User, however a User can have multiple Managers, Vendors, or Customers (each with a different Logo). I guess a 3rd option since Logo:Manager or Logo:Customer is always 1:1 is to put the Logo fields in the Manager or Customer table, but to be clean and for future changes, I'd like to have all the logo data in separate table(s).